# Why doesn't the IEEEtran bibliography style match the IEEE style guide?

Tags: bibtex, ieee-style

I am using the bibliography style "IEEEtran" with bibTeX, but it doesn't seem to match the IEEE style guide, specifically the format of the in-text citations.

I am using the "cite" package with the noadjust option.

My document has citations that look like this: [4,5] and [11-15].

The [IEEE style guide](https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/conferences/style_references_manual.pdf) (page 5, "EDITING REFERENCES") seems to call for in text citations that look like this: [4], [5] and [11]-[15].

I know I can cheat by calling `\cite{ref4}, \cite{ref5}`, but if I do that with sequential citations, as in `\cite{ref11}-\cite{ref15}`, then references 12, 13, and 14 won't be in my bibliography.

What am I doing wrong that makes me the only person asking this question?

Comment: did you try `\cite{ref11,ref12,ref,13,ref14,ref15}`?

Comment: Yes, that's what gives me [11-15], rather than [11]-[15].

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). If I just use the IEEEtran class, I get `[11], [12], [13], [14], [15]`. If I load the package `cite` which features compression of references, I get `[11]–[15]`.

Comment: I just tried to create an MWE using the IEEEtran class, and it works just fine. The problem is that I need to use a different, custom class, and I think that may be the issue.

Comment: Then your question tag is wrong (it does not concern the `IEEEtran` document class) and, furthermore, nobody can help you if do not provide a compilable MWE that exactly reproduces your undesired behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the tag. As for the MWE, it requires a custom class. Maybe I should begin a new question?

Comment: I guess you can edit the question. Maybe see what the custom classe is based on, or if the behavior is the same with standard classes, e.g. `article`?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks. I'll try it with some other classes and see what I get.